# How to Call Webservice with Ksoap in android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I have problem with call service ksoap in android, because api service containt note properties, so i don't call service, Please help me.

**This is api service**

```
 /api.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/RegisterEx"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <RegisterEx xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <objCustReg>
        <CustomerID>int</CustomerID>
        <Firstname>string</Firstname>
        <Lastname>string</Lastname>
        <Email>string</Email>
        <Passwd>string</Passwd>
        <Phone>string</Phone>
        <Address>string</Address>
        <City>string</City>
        <State>string</State>
        <Zipcode>string</Zipcode>
        <Country>string</Country>
        <RegisterDate>string</RegisterDate>
        <RegisteryBy>string</RegisteryBy>
        <Credit />
      </objCustReg>
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Passwd>string</Passwd>
    </RegisterEx>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**This is Code i call api service in android.**

```
              String nameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";
                String methodName = "RegisterEx";
                // EndPoint
                String endPoint = "http://xxxxx.info/xxxx.asmx";
                // SOAP Action
                String soapAction = "http://tempuri.org/RegisterEx";
                SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(nameSpace, methodName);
                SoapObject rpc2 = new SoapObject(nameSpace, methodName);
                rpc2.addProperty("CustomerID", "1");
                rpc2.addProperty("Firstname", "boy");
                rpc2.addProperty("Lastname", "boy");
                rpc2.addProperty("Email", "email@gmail.com");
                rpc2.addProperty("Passwd", "123456");
                rpc2.addProperty("Phone", "123465789");
                rpc2.addProperty("Address", "address");
                rpc2.addProperty("City", "city");
                rpc2.addProperty("State", "2222");
                rpc2.addProperty("Zipcode", "2222");
                rpc2.addProperty("RegisterDate", "");
                rpc2.addProperty("RegisteryBy", "");
                rpc2.addProperty("Country", "USA");
                rpc.addProperty("objCustReg", rpc2);
                rpc.addProperty("sWSUsername", "user");
                rpc.addProperty("sWSPasswd", "pass");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER10);

                envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(rpc);

                HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(endPoint);
                try {
                    transport.call(soapAction, envelope);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SoapObject object = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                result = object.getProperty(0).toString();
```

My code call service return null, Please help me. thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to add

```
envelope.implicitTypes=true;
```

, becouse currently objCustReg is of type RegisterEx.
And change

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
```

to

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

becouse of xsi and xsd in Your envelope is for 2001.

Are You sure, that it doesnt print exception stacktrace?